# Null pointer exception when testing a rest web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, unit-testing, nullpointerexception

I get a `NullPointerException` when trying to test a web service

My code:

```
@Path("/")
public class SubscriptionService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/status/{subsId}")
    public Response getSubscriptionStatus(@PathParam("subsId") int subsId) {
        return Response.status(200).entity("subscription status for id: " + subsId).build();
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestService {

    private SubscriptionService service;

    @Test
    public void testGetSubscriptionStatus() {
        final Response response = service.getSubscriptionStatus(5);

        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals("subscription status for id: 5", response.getEntity());
    }
}
```

The error appears here: `final Response response = service.getSubscriptionStatus(5);`

Does anyone have any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize `service`. So you get an NPE.

change:

```
private SubscriptionService service;
```

To:

```
private SubscriptionService service = new SubscriptionService();
```

Comment: What a silly mistake..Thanks that solved the problem. BR